# vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ is not a constructor

Tags: vuejs3

Starting a new Vue App and facing following err at initializing

my code is:

App.vue :

```
<template>
    <div>
      hi there
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    name: 'App'
};
</script>
```

main.js :

```
import * as Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App';

new Vue({
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

Got this err in browser so no content ('hi there') is rendered! :

```
Uncaught TypeError: vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ is not a constructor
    at eval (main.js?fbea:4:1)
    at Module../src/main.js (app.js:59:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:158:33)
    at app.js:1263:109
    at Function.__webpack_require__.O (app.js:204:23)
    at app.js:1264:53
    at app.js:1266:12
```

any ideas?

(no errors in my terminal)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My problem was because of the Vue version, I was using Vue-Js v3 but coding in version 2 (because of my tutorial course, believe me I'm not stupid LOL) which caused the errors.

There are lots of updates and one of the very basic of them is for initializing instead of using:

```
new Vue({
render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

I should've simply used:

```
createApp(App).mount('#app');
```

Answer (score 4):

Try changing your main.js code to this:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

If it works for you you will have to import each functionality individually, for example, if you want to add router and store then the code would be:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount('#app')
```

---

**Also..**

You may have to add this line before **createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount('#app')** depending on your versions of babel and vue:

```
export const eventBus = createApp(App);
```

Answer (score 0):

in webpack configuration file, sepecify `vue` to be imported

```json
resolve: [
  alias: {
    'vue': path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'vue', 'dist', 'vue.esm-browser.js'),
  }
]
```

works with `"vue": "^3.2.45"`

Comment: thx it work for me using Vue 3 in 2024

Answer (score 0):

While this can be a great many things thanks to the obtuse-ity of the error message in webpack, mine were 2 faulty directives when migrating from v2 to v3. Was a pain to debug, so if this helps just one soul - it would have been worth it :)

Try commenting out your directives and rebuild the app, see if that helps remove the error message.

Then follow this: https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/custom-directives.html